# External URL with mod_rewrite and mod_proxy in WAMP

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect, wampserver, mod-proxy

I am using WAMP on my local server, I am trying to redirect a local directory to an external domain name, for example:

http://myhost.dev/directory should redirect to http://www.google.com

However, I wish to keep http://myhost.dev/directory in the address bar. I understand that I need to set up mod_proxy, which after reading the documentation have found that I need to do this:

```
RewriteRule ^directory http://google.co.uk [P]
ProxyPassReverse /directory/ http://phvc.co.uk/schools/
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
[Mon Oct 22 10:41:22 2012] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] C:/wamp/www/vhosts/path/.htaccess: ProxyPassReverse not allowed here
```

If anyone can help with this, that would be appreciated.

I have turned on all the modules saying proxy in WAMP:

- proxy_module
- proxy_ajp_module
- proxy_balancer_module
- proxy_connect_module
- proxy_ftp_module
- proxy_http_module

Cheers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up implementing this solution:

http://nukoagency.co.uk/2012/11/accessing-an-iframe-using-a-proxy-server/